# Wpf Clickonce deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wpf-controls

I tried to do the clickonce deployment of a simple demo project. The project is deployed but when I click on the RUN button it gives the error that this application can not start and when I try to launch the application It gives the error that this application can not be installed. What wrong I am doing?

Comment: Give us the error no or something more about the error... Or try debug mode to see if you can find the error before deploying... Or have a screenshot attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the log file from a ClickOnce installation tells you what the problem is. I suggest you take a look at that file.

In my experience, it usually is some dependency that's missing.

Here's a useful guide: [Troubleshooting Specific Errors in ClickOnce Deployments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229001.aspx)

If you are using the Google Chrome web browser to launch ClickOnce applications, then take a look at the [Chrome Extension for ClickOnce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl).

Comment: I don't have any special thing in the project. I just followed a demo at windowsclient.com. What is the location of the log file? I could not find it.

Comment: Usually there's a Details button to click on. Click on it to look at the log file.

Comment: Thanks Magnus I just find out that the application is working fine in Internet Explorer. I was trying to launch it through google crome. Now any reason why it is not launching through crome.

Comment: Ok, then maybe you should take a look at the Chrome Extension for ClickOnce. I have added a link to it in my answer.